# Changing foreign key has no effect in EF4 code first

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have an entity defined using Entity Framework Code First that has an optional parent node field. A null parent node value means the entity's node is at the root. There will be multiple children under the same parent.

```
Class ContentDescriptor
{
    virtual ObjectId ParentObjectId{get;set;}
}
```

In DB Initializer:

```
HasOptional(contentDescriptor => contentDescriptor.ParentObjectId).WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentObjectId"));
```

The navigation property is assigned as following:

```
  DBContext.ContentDescriptors.Add(contentDescriptor);
  contentDescriptor.ParentObjectId = ObjectIdFactory.Save(parent);
```

ObjectIdFactory.Save checks if there is an entry in DBContext.ObjectId.Local, then  DBContext.ObjectId, if there is no record in memory or DB, then do an insert and return the result.

However, when new nodes are added to the context, only the first child of the parent get saved correctly. Second and later children are added to the root, even if they appear as the children of the parent in the local. Looks like the framework is unable to generate update queries for foreign key when the entity is being added.

My walkaround is to expose the foreign key in the entity and assign the foreign key manually, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution:

```
HasOptional(contentDescriptor => contentDescriptor.ParentObjectId).WithMany().
HasForeignKey(c=>c.ParentObjectIdRaw);
Property(c => c.ParentObjectIdRaw).HasColumnName("ParentObjectId");


contentDescriptor.ParentObjectIdRaw = contentDescriptor.ParentObjectId.ObjectIdId;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what usually works best for me (note: I'm using 4.3, I don't think it should be much different, but not sure)...
(I'm using pseudo `Node` for a self-referencing entity, all else is the same I think)

```
public class Node
{
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasOptional(n => n.Parent)
    .WithMany(n => n.Children);
```

...i.e. problem with your implementation may be the `WithOptionalDependent` which is usually for 1-to-1 relationships (you have 1 to many as you said).

On the usage side...

```
using (var db = new UserDbContext())
{
    var root = new Node { Name = "root" };
    var node = new Node { Name = "first", Parent = root };
    var child1 = new Node { Name = "child1", Parent = node };
    var child2 = new Node { Name = "child2", Parent = node };
    db.Nodes.Add(child1);
    db.Nodes.Add(child2);
    db.SaveChanges();
    foreach (var n in db.Nodes.Include(x => x.Parent))
        Console.WriteLine("node: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", n.Name, n.NodeID, n.Parent != null ? n.Parent.Name : "", n.Parent != null ? n.Parent.NodeID : 0, n.Children != null ? n.Children.Count : 0);
}
```

...as far as I can tell, you should just add children (which add parent automatically). Or use `Children` to add the other way around, so add children into parent nodes, in which case it's enough to save the root only.

not certain if this solves what you have (I'm not exactly sure what is that you're doing with `ObjectIdFactory.Save` behind) but it's the same pattern, and you don't have to save parents really, it's enough to save just a child before on `SaveChanges()`

hope this helps any

Comment: Basically every other entity has an ObjectId and I do not want introduce unnecessary joins in queries related to ObjectIds, so there is no collection property on the parent object id. I tried WithMany and setting navigation property but has no effect.

Comment: collection property doesn't 'add' anything, just gives you extra navigation property (that's the other part of the already existing relationship). Anyway, you can use '.WithMany()' and remove the collection, it doesn't change anything. And on my side all nodes are added correctly etc. Make sure you're not doing anything inside that method that is untypical

Comment: my entity relationship is a little different. Only some object types will a tree structure, other objects may have a flat list or other structure. The object types with a tree structure will have their relationship saved in the ContentDescriptor table. And all my look ups from partners are based on ObjectIds, Thus ParentObjectId went from a cache column to the sole column defining the parent-child relationship. Adding a ObjectId.ParentObjectId column would waste a lot of storage space, and ContentDescriptor.ParentContentDescriptor would be inefficient in searching.